# Configure Environment to Use Different Storage Paths on Amazon S3 with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I would like to have distinct folders in my S3 bucket to keep the production database clear from the development environment.
I am not sure how to do this, here is the skeleton I've come up with in the carrierwave initializer:

```
if Rails.env.test? or Rails.env.development?
   CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     //configure dev storage path
   end
end

if Rails.production?
   CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     //configure prod storage path
   end
end
```

Comment: That's good (except the typo in the if for production)

Comment: OK and how would you write the paths? Something like 'config.store_dir = "path"'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

**Option1: You don't care about organizing the files by model ID**

In your `carrierwave.rb` initializer:

```
Rails.env.production? ? (primary_folder = "production") : (primary_folder = "test")

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  # stores in either "production/..." or "test/..." folders
  config.store_dir = "#{primary_folder}/uploads/images"
end
```

**Option 2: You DO care about organizing the files by model ID (i.e. user ID)**

In your uploader file (i.e. `image_uploader.rb` within the `uploaders` directory):

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ...

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  def store_dir
    Rails.env.production? ? (primary_folder = "production") : (primary_folder = "test")

    # stores in either "production/..." or "test/..." folders
    "#{primary_folder}/uploads/images/#{model.id}"
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: OK and how would you write the path configuration? Something like `config.store_dir = "path"`?

Comment: I would even have it so that there is only an additional folder level for "test" and none for production. This way, when you are done with testing, you can easily delete the test folder and have shorter URLs for production data.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following initializer:

```
#config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.enable_processing = true

  # For testing, upload files to local `tmp` folder.
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.root = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"
  elsif Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file
    config.root = "#{Rails.root}/public/"
  else #staging, production
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
    }
    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads" # To let CarrierWave work on heroku
    config.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
    config.fog_public     = false
    config.storage = :fog
  end
end
```

- In development, the uploads are sent to the local public directory.
- In test mode, to the Rails tmp directory.
- And finally, in "else" environment (which is usually a production or staging environment) we direct the files to S3 using Environmental Variables to determine which bucket and AWS credentials to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use different Amazon s3 buckets for your different environments. In your various environment .rb files, set the environment specific `asset_host`. Then you can avoid detecting the Rails environment in your uploader.

For example, in production.rb:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "production_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

The asset_host in development.rb becomes:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "development_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

etc.

(Also consider using a CDN instead of hosting directly from S3).

Then your uploader becomes:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ...

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  def store_dir
    "uploads/images/#{model.id}"
  end

  ...

end
```

This is a better technique from the standpoint of replicating production in your various other environments.

Comment: Where does asset_host actually get read? Do you have to load it up yourself or does Carrier Wave automatically pick up on it?